# Is it possible to delete a dereferenced Pointer

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, delete-operator

I have some legacy code where a Object is dynamically allocated and then emitted:

```
QList<MyClass *> *list = new QList<MyClass *>();
...
emit listReady(*row);

void OtherClass::slotList(QList<MyClass> list) {
    ...
    delete list???
}
```

i can delete the objects in the list and i can clear the List, is it possible to delete the list itsef in my slot?

Comment: Should the first `list` (the pointer) actually be named `row`, to match its usage later?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is it possible to delete the list itsef in my slot?

No, it's not possible. Because your slot accept the list by value, which is copy of original `QList<MyClass *> *list` object.

`void OtherClass::slotList(QList<MyClass> list)`

To be able delete the `list` object you should change the `slotList` arguments to accept the pointer to `list`.

Comment: Ok means i can delete my list after emitting it because the slow will get a copy??

Comment: @wutzebaer in this particular case - yes. But in another cases, when list will contains objects by value, removing this list will give excess overhead (copy object to new list,  delete them from old list) and it's easier to pass the list into the slot by pointer.

Comment: @ikleschenkov Qt containers are implicitly shared with copy-on-write. Copying the list does *not* automatically copy all of its elements.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the way you wrote it. `list` the parameter is passed by value, so it's a *copy* of the list to which the pointer `list` points (it might help clarity of your question if you gave the two variables distinct names).

Even if you changed `slotList` to take its parameter by reference (`slotList(QList<MyClass> &list)`), it would still not be a good idea to `delete &list` inside. That's because it Qt, some signal-slot connections (such as queued connections or connections across threads) do not operate directly on the signal's parameters, but on their copies.

If, for some reason, you need to propagate ownership of the list from the creator signal to the slot and delete it there, you must change the slot to accept a pointer instead:

```
QList<MyClass *> *row = new QList<MyClass *>();
...
emit listReady(row);

void OtherClass::slotList(QList<MyClass> *list) {
    ...
    delete list;
}
```

However, the most important question is: why are you actually allocating the `QList` dynamically in the first place? Containers (like `QList`) very rarely require dynamic allocation. That holds even more for Qt containers which are implemented with implicit sharing and copy-on-write, so even copying a `QList` is cheap (it does not copy its contents). The correct solution for you is therefore most likely to have `row` be an object instead of a pointer, and forget the entire `new`/`delete` business.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible, as `list` is not (the same) pointer nor reference to `*list` (in which case you could `delete &list;` (yes, a dirty hack) - only in case of direct connection) and is passed by value instead.

Why are you dynamically allocating the list in the first place?